# What is the C:\EFI folder on Windows 10 Technical Preview and should a user be able to modify it?

Tags: windows-10-preview, efi

I have not seen a folder named `C:\EFI` before, but I was wondering why the default permissions are not more restrictive. Every user could just delete that folder.

What is this folder and is it correct, that any user can modify it?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Disk Management.

Answer (score 1):

On such machines the computer executes code inside an \Efi folder rather than code stored on hidden sectors on the disk.
EFI is only supported on 64 bit versions of the operating system.

http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_efi_folder_for_in_the_windows_7_install_disk